# How to change text on mouse over with transition

Tags: jquery, transition, mouseover

I try go get my head around how this was done.
All I know it uses jquery

http://www.marieforleo.com/

See the logo/text in the left top corner... when you mouseover it, it shows a random texts with a transition and defaults back to the site name on mouse out.

How was this done?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: could be done with javascript (jquery, velocity, doesn't matter) or plain css. try to inspect that logo in chrome. Ok maybe not css (because text is always different).

Comment: it's probably just an array of sentences which on mouseover, one will be selected randomly and placed as the text then a slide out animation will happen - or in this case they seem to append a letter of the esntence at at time

Comment: you should probably still recognize my answer. I've put some effort in it you know :)

Comment: Sorry AIFra, I really appreciate that you took the time to help me. I was away a day and very busy the day before also I just saw the message about your answer 10 minutes ago and came here directly. Thanks a lot and sorry again!!

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps you! It's not exactly the same, but still... You can still improve some functionality and you can work on code re-usability.

```js
(function($) {

  var logo = $("#logo"),
    originalText = logo.html(),
    altLogoTextArray = ["make it count.", "make peace.", "make art not war.", "make something out of yourself."],
    chosenText,
    timeOut = null;

  function animateText(text, startFrom, length, delay) {
    var strlen = text.length;
    if (startFrom + length > strlen) {
      return;
    }
    timeOut = window.setTimeout(function() {
      logo.html(text.substr(0, startFrom) + text.substr(startFrom, length));
      //testText.html(startFrom + length);
      animateText(text, startFrom, length + 1, delay);
    }, delay);
  }

  function getRandomTextFromArray(arr) {
    var arrLength = arr.length,
      randInt = Math.floor(Math.random() * (arrLength - 0)) + 0;
    return arr[randInt];
  }

  logo.on('mouseenter mouseleave', function(e) {
    window.clearTimeout(timeOut);
    if (e.type == "mouseenter") {
      chosenText = getRandomTextFromArray(altLogoTextArray);
      animateText(chosenText, 3, 0, 20);
    } else if (e.type == "mouseleave") {
      animateText(originalText, 3, 0, 20);
    }
  });

})(window.jQuery);
```

```css
#logo {
  font-size: 30px;
  min-width: 500px;
  display: inline-block;
  zoom: 1;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#logo:after {
  content:"";
  display:block;
  height:1px;
  width:22px;
  background:#000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<span id="logo">marie forleo.</span>
```

Comment: Hello AIFra, thanks a lot for your answer and sorry for not coming back earlier I was away for a day!! I'll try your solution and tell you how it worked!
Thanks again!